# Laravel Crop Image Before Upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm new to Jquery. I'm building a project with Laravel 7.28. I want users to crop an image before upload. I've searched on the net but all examples upload the image right after cropping. But I want the user to crop but not upload. I want users to upload the cropped image with input fields. Here is my form and script code:

```
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
            <!-- Basic Forms -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h4 class="box-title">Quick Offer Creation</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="card-text">
                        @if (count($errors) > 0)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::open(['route'=>['quick_offer.store'], 'method' => 'POST', 'class'=> 'form', 'files' => true ]) !!}
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-6">

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="project_id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Project</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select name="project_id" id="" class="form-control select2">
                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                        @foreach($projects as $project)
                                            <option
                                                value="{{ $project->id }}" {{ old('project_id') == $project->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $project->code . ', ' . $project->title}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="bedroom" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Bedroom</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="bedroom" name="bedroom"
                                           value="{{ old('bedroom') }}" min="1">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="location" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Location</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="location" name="location"
                                           value="{{ old('location') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-form-label">Status</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                    <select name="status" id="" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                        <option value="publish" {{ old('status') == 'publish' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Publish
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="draft" {{ old('status') == 'draft' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Draft
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="review" {{ old('status') == 'review' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Review
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="unpublish" {{ old('status') == 'unpublish' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Unpublish
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                                    Image
                                    <br>
                                    <small>The photo must be square</small>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="file" name="photo" class="image form-control" value="{{ old('photo') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6">

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="currency" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-form-label">Currency</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                    <select name="currency" id="" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                        <option value="TRY" {{ old('currency') == 'TRY' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            (₺) Turkish Lira
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="EUR" {{ old('currency') == 'EUR' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            (€) Euro
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="USD" {{ old('currency') == 'USD' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            ($) American Dollar
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="GBP" {{ old('currency') == 'GBP' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            (£) GBP
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="price" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Normal Price</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="price" name="price"
                                           min="0" value="{{ old('price') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="discounted_price" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Discounted Price</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" id="discounted_price"
                                           name="discounted_price"
                                           min="0" value="{{ old('discounted_price') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="button_link" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Call to Action Link</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="url" id="button_link" name="button_link"
                                           value="{{ old('button_link') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                                    <select name="company" id="" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                        <option
                                            value="londonist_investments" {{ old('company') == 'londonist_investments' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Londonist Investments
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="turyap_uk" {{ old('company') == 'turyap_uk' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Turyap UK
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                                <label for="key_points" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Key Points</label>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="One to each line"
                                              name="key_points" id="key_points"
                                              style="width: 100%; min-height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;">{{ old('key_points')}}</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12">

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Save
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel"
                             aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Laravel Cropper Js - Crop Image Before
                                            Upload - Tutsmake.com</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="img-container">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                                    <img id="image"
                                                         src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/3456749">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="preview"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="crop">Crop</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('js')

    <script>
        var $modal = $('#modal');
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        var cropper;
        $("body").on("change", ".image", function(e){
            var files = e.target.files;
            var done = function (url) {
                image.src = url;
                $modal.modal('show');
            };
            var reader;
            var file;
            var url;
            if (files && files.length > 0) {
                file = files[0];
                if (URL) {
                    done(URL.createObjectURL(file));
                } else if (FileReader) {
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        done(reader.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            }
        });
        $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                aspectRatio: 1,
                viewMode: 3,
                preview: '.preview'
            });
        }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            cropper.destroy();
            cropper = null;
        });
        $("#crop").click(function(){
            canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                width: 800,
                height: 800,
            });
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    var base64data = reader.result;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "crop-image-upload",
                        data: {'_token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'), 'image': base64data},
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            $modal.modal('hide');
                            alert("Crop image successfully uploaded");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.js"></script>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Better to do resizing in controller, using `intervention/image`

[Package Link](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

[Tutorial Link](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-resize-image-before-upload-exampleexample.html)

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks but I want users to do the cropping inside the form. I don't have enough skills to customize JS part.